# Why does the subtraction work for the first if but not the second?

Tags: c

On the last line of each if statement the current array element in 'ciphered_text' has 26 subtracted from it. However, this only appears to be working for the first section and not in the second. Can anyone see why? As an aside can anyone tell me whether I should be using else if or else here. Thanks.

```
    for(arrayelement = 0; arrayelement < size; arrayelement++)
    {
        ciphered_text[arrayelement] = (plain_text[arrayelement]);
        if ((int)(ciphered_text[arrayelement]) >= 65 && (int)(ciphered_text[arrayelement]) <= 90)
        {
            ciphered_text[arrayelement] = (int)(ciphered_text[arrayelement]) + shiftkey;
            if (ciphered_text[arrayelement] > 90)
                ciphered_text[arrayelement] = (int)(ciphered_text[arrayelement]) - 26;

        }

else if ((int)(ciphered_text[arrayelement])  >= 97 && (int)(ciphered_text[arrayelement]) <= 122)
        {
            ciphered_text[arrayelement] = (int)(ciphered_text[arrayelement]) + shiftkey;
            if (ciphered_text[arrayelement] > 122)
                ciphered_text[arrayelement] = (int)(ciphered_text[arrayelement]) - 26;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens the second time? You should try debugging this code. It is hard to help you with your snippet you should provide an example which compiles.

Comment: @user1827332 - Please do not delete huge chucks of the original question. People may wish to view it and now the answers does not make any sense. Just put *EDIT* and add to the original questions. By all means correct typos.

Comment: @user1827332 - Put the original question back for you. Just accept an answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose `ciphered_text` is a `char[N]` or a `char*`?

The likely cause of failure is then that

```
(int)(ciphered_text[arrayelement]) + shiftkey;
```

is larger than 127, and when that is stored in a `char` (`ciphered_element[arrayelement]`), it is converted to a negative value. (Note: conversion of out-of-range values to `char` is implementation-defined if `char` is signed.)

The easiest fix would be to change the type to `unsigned char`.

Comment: It works for the top one one though, all that is different is that the ascii values of the characters in the second if are higher as the chars are lower case

Comment: Yes, and the value of `shiftKey` has never been large enough to cause overflow for the smaller values, apparently, @user1827332.

Comment: `unsigned char` can hold values from 0 to 255 (if `CHAR_BIT == 8`, which almost universally is the case, to `2^CHAR_BIT - 1` generally), while `char` can be either signed or unsigned and usually is signed and the largest number it can hold is then 127 (_usually_, larger for larger `CHAR_BIT`). So by giving it a range that reaches higher, overflow is avoided.