# Caesar cipher in C - unexpected problems

Tags: c

I'm facing unexpected problem in my Caesar'c cipher. Caesar is when you encrypt text by shifting every letter by n numbers. So if it is 1, abc will be bcd. I work on the program that does that in C, but it works strange for some characters, regular letters, although it should be correct. Here is the problem syntax:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
{   
    if (text[i] != ' ')
    {
       // printf("\n%i\n", key);

        text[i] = text[i] + key;


        if (text[i] > 122)
        {
            text[i] = text[i] + 97 - 122; 
        }


    }
}
```

I wrap around by doing that math in the end.
Can you please help me whats wrong with it?

EDIT: This code is fine, problem is with handling of command line parameters.

Comment: Can you show what exactly is "wrong" ie an input an output text?

Comment: The wrap around code won't work for uppercase characters. Also consider using 'a' and 'z' instead of 97 and 122.

Comment: @fvu  I have found an error, it is incorrect handling of argv[], when I do 2 digit number i still get 1 digit, I will need to look into it elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have problems witch some particular letters or all of them?

Comment: @codewarrior not really on topic, but I have int main (int argc, string argv[]). I read it by doing atoi(argv[1]) and this reads only 1 digit. How do I read few digits as one int from argv?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the subtraction work for the first if but not the second?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416698/why-does-the-subtraction-work-for-the-first-if-but-not-the-second)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `96` in place of `97` problem solved

so when you wrap around then actually increase by 1 extra value
think of this;

```
    ------------------------------------------
    a  |  b |  c |  d  | . . . x  |  y  |  z  |
    --------------------------------------------
    97 | 98 | 99 | 100 | . . .120 | 121 | 122 |
    -------------------------------------------
```

Try using 'a' , 'b' , .. .. .. ,'z' like this rather their actual values

using `' '`single quote inside char gives you integral value i.e. ASCII value

here is the code :

```
char c;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
{   
    if (text[i] != ' ')
    {
       // printf("\n%i\n", key);

        c=text[i];    
        text[i] = text[i] + key;

        if(c >='a' && c <='z' && text[i] >'z')
            text[i] = text[i] + 'a' -1 - 'z' ; 

        if(c >='A' && c <= 'Z' && text[i] > 'Z')
            text[i] = text[i] + 'A' -1 - 'Z' ; 

    }
}
```

Comment: Yor upgrade with upper case letters will ruin this program. Notice that e.g a is > Z

Comment: Also, my variant works fine. I don't need to change it to 96, it works as it should with expected output.

Comment: This (else if) will not help either... still if first if will fail with a else if will be ok as mentioned in first comment.